# No sound from remote notification

Tags: notifications, swift3, ios10

Could some one help me to understand why i'm not receiving sound from remote notifications in IOS 10 Swift 3.

Here is my code:
AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool {
        let settings = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        settings.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound]) {(granted, error) in
        }
    return true
    }

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        let viewController = self.window?.rootViewController as! LoadingCloudDataViewController
        let notification: CKNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo as! [String: NSObject])
        if(notification.notificationType == CKNotificationType.query) {
            let queryNotification = notification as! CKQueryNotification
            let recordID = queryNotification.recordID
            viewController.fetchRecord(recordID: recordID!)
        }
    }
```

And here is the notification subscription code:

```
func subscriptionNotificationsKcal() {
        publicDatabase = container.publicCloudDatabase
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
        let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Kcal", predicate: predicate, options: .firesOnRecordCreation)
        let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
        notificationInfo.alertBody = "New Calories Item was Added"
        notificationInfo.shouldBadge = true
        subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
        publicDatabase?.save(subscription, completionHandler: ({returnRecord, error in
            if let err = error {
                print("subscription failed %@", err.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                print("sub success")
            }
        }))
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the sound is muted. To activate it, in the case of this example, use the following code:

```
notificattionInfo.soundName = "default"
```